# Is it possible using the django framework to load a html file in jQuery without creating a url in urls.py

Tags: jquery, html, django

Is it possible to create a html file that can be loaded from jQuery using whatever mechanism ($.load, $.get, etc) without having the html loaded through the django url->view->template framework.

I'd like to have a file - test.html which has some jQuery that loads some html from test_popup.html and appends the html to a div on test.html.

But, I don't want to create url in django for accessing the test_popup.html page.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's a static html file, then put it in your static files directory.

Then load you can load the url e.g. `/static/test_html.html` with jQuery without adding any further url patterns.

If you need further help, refer to the docs on [managing static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#managing-static-files).

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to serve files (which can be of any kind) through Django, you should configure your webserver to handle those requests which is recommended anyway.
In your apache .conf you could add an Alias like this:

```
Alias /your/url /var/www/vhosts/your.domain.com/your/path/

<Directory /var/www/vhosts/your.domain.com/your/path>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Youll have to adapt the local filesystem path as well as the url you want to use.
Hope this helps.